# MIP SDK: Applying Sensitivity Label to Doc file, unable to open it

Tags: microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I am trying to apply a sensitivity label with protection to a .doc file. The process does not report an error but I am unable to open the file after applying the label. This is what I see in MS Word:

[image]

The Azure Information Protection Viewer shows this:

[image]

I am a site collection administrator, I am not sure why I am unable to view these files. I have the same issue if I try to protect any of the non-native files such as .dwg -> .dwg.pfile. If I try to protect files such as .jpg -> .pjpg, the files open without any issues.
If I use the AIP tool to protect these files, the files open without any issues.

Could anyone point me to what might be going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the protection label has been created with the "Co-Author" permission, the issue is replicated. Creating a new label with the "Co-Owner" permission resolves the issue.